# Discrepancy in GA4 Pageviews

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I noticed in GA4 debugger that all Pageviews are not being received.  Is this common?  I've never seen issues in Debugger like this before.

Over the last month, there has been about an 13% difference in page views (fewer in Google Analytics 4).

What should I expect?  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

I've set up Google Analytics 4 via Google Tag Manager. It is set with stock settings - firing on All Pages.  Everything in the Google Tag Manager debugger checks out and reads just fine.  All tags are firing as expected.  The location of the GTM code is in the `<head>` near the top of the page.  I've tested staying on the page after it loads, and then checking... and checking immediately.  It seems like it only fires events (page_view) some of the time, but not all of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded this is a bug in the GA4 debugview.  We as marketers cannot rely on this tool at the moment.  The issue seems to be resolved.  Now there seems to be a similar bug/[new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745048/all-events-duplicated-in-google-analytics-4-debugger).

Answer (score 0):

You want to pay attention to batched GA4 events. They take time to be sent since they anticipate more events to include in the same payload.

If you still don't see them firing consistently, use the GTM preview debugger to debug the pageview tag firing properly, investigating the event on which it should have fired and going inside the tag having the event selected to see its triggers issues.

Comment: My issue with the debugger is that when it is running it doesn't batch, so I can see all GTM tags firing and GA4 traffic in the network console so you get a false sense of confidence. I am testing something at the moment, and I am firing internal link events that should fire before the page changes, but the results are sporadic where sometimes it fires and sometimes it doesn't. Not convinced that batching is working i.e. if you leave the page before the batch fires it won't fire, even though Google docs say that it should be using the browser navigation beacon by default.

Comment: then it's not batching, it's your implementation. You're hitting some race conditions. If by debugger you mean the preview mode, then yes, it disables batching. There are many debuggers for GA4 testing. And one preview.

Comment: If it works perfectly without batching (debug mode), and works sporadically when batching is applied, I'm not sure how to get to the root of the problem. If I fire a console log in a custom html tag for the same trigger with same parameters sent to GA4 (i.e. after the work is done) when not in debug mode, it logs to the console, showing the tag has been injected and the code is running - it's just the GA4 tracking that doesn't seem to be firing. If you have any recommendations for debuggers that don't trigger debugging mode for GA4 it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I use adswerev's debugger for GA4 debugging. The extension Google wrote has been useless for years. They would actually do less harm if they remove it from the chrome store.