# Duplicate link clicks in GA4 (via Google Tag Manager)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

For some reason, I am getting duplicate link clicks in GA4.

In GA4, I left the Outbound clicks tracking turned ON in Enhanced Measurement so it tracks Outbound clicks.

With regards to Internal clicks, I wanted to track these using GTM. So I've created an Auto Event variable with Component Type Is Outbound.

Then I've created a trigger of type Click - Just Links -> Some Link Clicks and set it to fire only if the Auto Event variable equals false (i.e. is not an outbound click).
This trigger fires a GA4 Event tag which sends "click" event name with "click_url" and "click_text" parameters.

When I test this, it seems to be working fine until it doesn't.
Link clicks are showing up (outbound clicks are showing with the "link_url" parameter which is correct - it's being added by the Enhanced Measurement; internal clicks are showing with the "click_url" and "click_text" parameters which is again correct - it's being added by GTM).

[image]

However, after some time of testing and clicking, it just stops working and Debug View timeline shows duplicates.

And what's strange is that rather than adding those duplicates to the timeline straight away, it doesn't add them until I click another link.

Upon clicking another link, the existing "click" and "page_view" events are duplicated for the previous action (that's already happened like half a minute ago on the timeline).

[image]

I've made sure that the tag is only firing once, no additional gtag command is used elsewhere in the code and it's not being created by the "Create event" functionality in GA4.

It's driving me insane, can anybody please help me?

PS: Testing it on a live site using the Live Report, it seems to be working (no duplicating of data).

Comment: It looks like an error of preview mode. Try to refresh the page.

Comment: That doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

In short, you're debugging it incorrectly. Despite the name, Debug View is not the best debugging tool. Also, GA4's interface is quite bugged, so you want to avoid using it when you have better options. Industry experts almost never use the debug view in GA4. It was just blindly copied from Firebase, where it made sense. Looks like they made mistakes while copying.

Longer answer on this problem is here: [All events duplicated in Google Analytics 4 Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745048/all-events-duplicated-in-google-analytics-4-debugger/75747001#75747001)

Comment: Seems like you've got a point, thank you for the direction! I've found out it doesn't only affect the link clicks, but everything. However, I've tried the steps you sent and in the Network tab, it's all showing correctly. It's still so strange though, as in another GA4 property I've never had problems with this.