# GA4 - Custom Event firing Twice

Tags: google-analytics-4

**Issue: GA4 custom event triggers twice**

I created an html page and added the tracking snippet to it's  section directly, not using Google Tag Manager.
This page has a webform which is submitted to the URL
/webform-title-thankyou

I created a custom event i.e. page_location equals https://example.com//webform-title-thankyou

The event triggers but twice, no UA property linked or anything that can cause the event triggering twice, please suggest a solution.

Attached screenshots
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9kAB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnh12.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this question: [All events duplicated in Google Analytics 4 Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745048/all-events-duplicated-in-google-analytics-4-debugger)

In short: you're debugging it incorrectly. Use proper debugging tools, namely, the Network tab of your devtools.